# SQL Server : convert char to float and round it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with a column of `VARCHAR2` type keeping a value like: `398566,569885`

What I need is to cast this number to float and then to make it looking like: `398566,56`
Casting it to float is **not** so important, if It's possible to trim the numbers it will be also ok.

What I have tried is:

```
select
cast (p1.VALUE as float) as Total
from Workflow p
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p1 on p1.ID=p.ID AND p1.NAME = 'Total'
WHERE p.TYPE = 'Marketing'
```

Is there a way to trim these numbers or to round it somehow?

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server doesn't have a `VARCHAR2` datatype (that would be Oracle) ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will round your numbers

```
select cast(value as decimal(9,2)) 
from workflow...
```

Comment: it's throwing: "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric."

Comment: You may need to increase the `9` value depending on the largest value in your data.

Comment: seems to be working but it's returning +1 in the results. For exampe 5698.6548 is casted to 5698.66

Comment: @podiluska I'm 99% sure SQL Server cannot round 5698.6548 to 5698.66. Only way to do it I can imagine is to do bankers' rounding. C# round work as banker's rounding by default, though

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
declare @a nvarchar(max)
select @a = '398566,569885'
select cast(@a as decimal(29, 2))
```

But then you'll receive **398566.57** because of rounding
To get **398566.56** you have to use round function with specified third parameter - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx (When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.)

```
select cast(round(cast(@a as decimal(29, 10)), 2, 1) as decimal(29, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you only want to reformat a VARCHAR column containing some (European) decimal text to 2 places.

```
select
left(p1.value, charindex(',', p1.value + ',')+2) as Total
from Workflow p
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p1 on p1.ID=p.ID AND p1.NAME = 'Total'
WHERE p.TYPE = 'Marketing';
```

And if you consistently want the 2 decimal places, then

```
select
left(p1.value + ',00', charindex(',', p1.value + ',')+2) as Total
from Workflow p
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p1 on p1.ID=p.ID AND p1.NAME = 'Total'
WHERE p.TYPE = 'Marketing';
```